# ASP.NET MVC Binding array to DropDownFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an array that i want to bind to a dropdown. Here is the code:

```
@for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
{
    @for (int j = 1; j <= 7; j++)
    {
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => @Model.Periods, new SelectList(@Model.Items, "Id", "Title", @Model.ScheduleList[i, j]))
    }
}
```

@Model.Periods is an ordinary **empty** integer array. @Model.ScheduleList is a two dimensional integer array and holds the values of the option that should be selected on binding. 
If I replace:

```
@Model.Periods
```

with:

```
@Model.Periods[i*10 + j]
```

The selected values are being shown but the generated *select* input has name like for example Periods[34], not just Periods and I get *null* in my view model on postback.
So my question is: How can I bind an oridnary array to dropdown and pass it the selected value with another array?

Comment: It's hard to understand what result you are trying to achieve, you want to have 5 * 7 = 35 dropdowns?

Comment: Yes, I want 35 dropdowns that should be saved to the database and later the user can edit them. In @Model.ScheduleList I have the values from the database, but I can't change the generated select input to show tham insted of the default first element

Comment: `@Model.Periods[i*10 + j]` is 'almost' correct - to post back that data you have to post it back with all values from Periods[0] to Periods[34], if any of Periods[X] (where X is from 0 to 34 included) will be missing, you won't receive correct data. Also index of array should strictly start from 0. So probably `@Model.Periods[(i-1)*10 + (j-1)]` should be fine.

Comment: You are completely right! Maybe you can write this in a separate answer so I can mark it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Model.Periods[i*10 + j] is not 100% correct - to post that data to your COntroller you have to post it back with all values starting from `Periods[0]` straight to `Periods[5 * 7 - 1]`.

If any of `Periods[X]` (where X is from 0 to 34 included) will be missing, you won't receive correct data. Also index of array should strictly start from 0.

So for example:

```
Periods[0] = 1
Periods[1] = 2
Periods[2] = 3
Periods[4] = 4
```

Will be bound to following array: `[1, 2, 3]`, because there's no payload item with sequential index between 2 and 4.

For payload:

```
Periods[1] = 1
Periods[2] = 2
Periods[3] = 3
Periods[4] = 4
```

Result will be `null` - first index of the array is missing in the payload.

So for you probably `@Model.Periods[(i-1)*10 + (j-1)]` should be fine.

If you **really** need your indexes be non-sequential, you can use this work-around: for each element add hidden field:

```
<input type="hidden" name="Periods.Index" value="{your index}" />
```

So your code will look this way:

```
@for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
{
    @for (int j = 1; j <= 7; j++)
    {
        <input type="hidden" name="Periods.Index" value="@(i * j)" /> 
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => @Model.Periods, new SelectList(@Model.Items, "Id", "Title", @Model.ScheduleList[i, j]))
    }
}
```

But this is not to be used in your current scenario. More info on indexers can be found in the web - for ex. on http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/